# Facebook like button shows comment (xfbml problem)

Tags: javascript, facebook, user-interface, facebook-like

I can't figure this problem out, what am i doing wrong? When i click on my like button, i want the information to be sent to the persons wall, i've seen this been done many times. However, when i click my like button, a comment box pops up, and i need to fill it out, then send it to my facebook wall, how can i get rid of this?

Image showing my problem,

[image: Facebook comment problem]

My code looks like this,

```
<fb:like href="MY_URL" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

When someone clicks the like button, it sends it to the facebook wall like you want it too. The comment box that pops up simply allows users to add a comment to the "like". If someone adds a comment in addition to pressing the like button, the post is treated with more importance by facebook (IE will show up higher on other people's news feeds etc). If you do not want the comment box to pop up (which I don't know why you wouldn't...) use the iframe like button instead of the XFBML like button.

Comment: The iframe version shows this box as well. To sort the issue, I'm subscribed to the events for like and unlike and check the DOM for the presence of a second iframe. If found it gets a gift from me - display: none. :)